# Writing Python validation script for different data files from different data sources on premises for different rules

Tags: python, azure, validation, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

i am new to python and i want to move data files from different on premises data sources to azure data lake storage and i want to validate these data files for different rules of validation before the get moved using azure data factory pipeline and azure databrick

I am aware how to create custome python copy activity in databricks for running python script

i need help with writing the script for validation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a coding or tutorial resource.  This posting is too broad for Stack Overflow.  For generic help, one generally uses tutorial materials and examples from the documentation for that module or package.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) to move files between different storages. It's pretty straightforward and scalable and you can even create Data Flow pipelines based on a Spark Cluster without having to write a single line of code.